# Is Portable.BouncyCastle cross-platform?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, bouncycastle

Will Portable.BouncyCastle works on Linux & MacOS if I reference it from an ASP.NET Core 2 web application? Will my ASP.NET Core 2 app still be cross-platform compatible?

Comment: Yes, because it's a .Net Standard 2.0 library

Answer (score 10):

No it is not cross-platform. It uses some types like `System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters` that are only implemented in .Net Core for Windows. See https://github.com/novotnyllc/bc-csharp/issues/6

Indeed, as of 2022-03-10, Portable.BouncyCastle [still uses the `RSACryptoServiceProvider(CspParameters)` constructor,](https://github.com/novotnyllc/bc-csharp/blob/a3ffd09890cd48bbd21040a49a2399a24f204918/crypto/src/security/DotNetUtilities.cs#L246) and .Net Core [still has it stubbed out for non-Windows.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5ce2b9f860f7a84c3059650bb67817d59d8f4953/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/src/System/Security/Cryptography/RSACryptoServiceProvider.Unix.cs#L35-L37)

Just because something targets .Net Standard doesn't mean it works on non-Windows OSes. There are many .Net Core implementations of .Net Standard API that are just stubs which throw "not implemented on this platform" exceptions.